# Multivariate distributions

Tags: self-study, multivariate-distribution

Let $x$ and $y$ be random variables with the following joint density function:
$f(x,y) = e^{-x}$ for $0<x< \infty$, and $0<y<1$

If $z= x+2y$, what is the joint density function of $x$ and $z$. 
Can we first find the PDF of x and then z and then multiply the two. With that approach the answer doesn’t match

Comment: Could you clarify what "e^-x for 0" might mean?  That phrase doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Sorry for typo ; it should be e^-x for 0<x< infinity and 0<y<1

Comment: I wanted to understand how to find the joint function of x and z

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that change and, to the extent possible, outline any initial steps or research you have taken to address this question.  Tag it with [tag:self-study] and please read the tag wiki (found by following the link).

Comment: Edited.. request if you can help

Comment: Your joint density function is separable in its parameters $x$ and $y$. That means the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. You can also directly see what their distributions are. That should allow you to compute the distribution of $Z=X+2Y$.

Comment: Then how to compute the joint function of  x z ?

Answer (score 3):

You can not multiply the density functions of $x$ and $z$, because $x$ and $z$ are not independent. We want to transform the joint density from $(x,y)$ to $(x,z)$. Denote $$x=g_1(x,y)=x$$ and $$z=g_2(x,y)=x+2y$$
We have the Jacobian matrix

$$
J=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then using the bivariate transformation formula, and observe that $y=(z-x)/2$, we have
$$f_{x,z}(x, z)=f_{x,y}(x, (z-x)/2)\times|J|^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x},\ 0<x<z<x+2<\infty$$
To verify this is a valid joint pdf, we can check
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{x+2}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dzdx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=1$$